# error when trying to tie React App to GraphQL query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-server

Here's the deal, all I'm doing is trying to render Thoughts on the homepage. Here's my code:

**client > src > pages > Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';

// Import ThoughtList query from components
import ThoughtList from '../components/ThoughtList';

// Import useQuery Hook from Apollo's React Hooks library
/* Allows us to make requests to the GraphQL server we connected
   to and made available to app using <ApolloProvider> component
   in App.js file */
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';

// Import thought query from query.js file
import { QUERY_THOUGHTS } from '../utils/queries';


const Home = () => {

  // Use useQuery hook to make query requests
  const { loading, data } = useQuery(QUERY_THOUGHTS);

  // Accessing thoughts query to render thoughts on homepage
  const thoughts = data.thoughts || [];
  console.log(thoughts);


  return (
    <main>
      <div className='flex-row justify-space-between'>
        <div className='col-12 mb-3'>
          {loading ? (
            <div> Loading... </div>
          ) : (
            <ThoughtList thoughts={thoughts} title="Some Feed for Thought(s)..." />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};


export default Home;
```

I get an error on  `const thoughts = data?.thoughts || [];`
It keeps rendering the ( . ) as an unexpected token. What could that mean?

Comment: It means that whatever is parsing your javascript, does not support this (relatively new) syntax. Something in your stack might be out of date.

Comment: use `<ThoughtList thoughts={data && data.thoughts} title="Some Feed for Thought(s)..." />` instead of unconditional data props access while it can be undefined (during loading) ... rethink why usually (and in docs!!) early return is used like `if (loading) return <Loading/>` - it prevents following code errors

Comment: Ok, so I'm not sure what I did, but whatever it was fixed it. I want to say once I connected the auth,js file to authenticate the login tokens, it allowed the server to release info pertaining to rendering the thoughts on the homepage. Thanks for trying to help though.